# Is it WCAG-compliant to have a div with role=heading with children?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

I'm working on making an existing React website more accessible. There is a piece of code that I would like to improve:

```
<div className={Styles.headline2}>This title is visually smaller.</div>
<div className={Styles.headline3}>This title is visually bigger.</div>
```

When audited, it was found that these two `div`s should be headings. Due to styling, I plan on using `role="heading"` instead of the `h2` HTML tag. Is it okay to define a `div` with children like below or would that be considered incorrect, accessibility-wise?

```
<div role="heading" aria-level="2">
  <div className={Styles.headline2}>This title is visually smaller.</div>
  <div className={Styles.headline3}>This title is visually bigger.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobinZigmond has good info in their answer.  Note that if you implement your "children" example, when you navigate with a screen reader, some screen readers will treat the "smaller" and "bigger" headings as separate screen reader "tab stops" and they'll read them as separate elements, although both will say "heading level 2".

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not correct. You will end up with assistive technologies - like screenreaders - thinking there is a single level 2 heading here, whose content is "This title is visually smaller. This title is visually bigger.".

The correct way to make these semantically headings is either to do this, if you must use ARIA:

```
<div className={Styles.headline2} role="heading" aria-level="2">This title is visually smaller.</div>
<div className={Styles.headline3} role="heading" aria-level="2">This title is visually bigger.</div>
```

(or whatever the appropriate `aria-level` values are - I'll comment more on this in a bit)

or, better, use the actual elements (again the precise heading levels - which in this case means the actual heading elements - are potentially up for debate):

```
<h2 className={Styles.headline2}>This title is visually smaller.</h2>
<h2 className={Styles.headline3}>This title is visually bigger.</h2>
```

I know you say you can't do this "due to styling" but I can't see this being a good reason. Sure, browsers have default styles for heading elements which you may not want to use - but then just override these with CSS! I assume that the `className`s that you are supplying are already setting the styles you would want - that shouldn't have to change just because you're now using a different (and semantically correct) element.

As for which heading levels you should use - that depends on the overall content of your page, but I can't think of anything sensible here. The fact that you have 2 headings right after each other, with no text or other content inbetween, only makes any sense to me if the first is the heading for a section and the next one the heading of the first "subsection". That would normally mean making the second one one level "lower" that the first - so if the first is an `h2`, the second would be an `h3`.

But then it doesn't make any sense for the less important heading - the hypothetical `h3` - to be "visually bigger", as you say it is.

Headings should follow a particular structure which mirrors the structure of your page's content - see eg [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#accessibility_concerns) for more on this. So you need to mark up the levels - whether with `aria-level` on a `<div role="heading">` or (much better) with actual heading elements doesn't matter here - in such a way that your content will make sense to screenreader users who only have access to the list of headings. (This is similar to a sighted user quickly scanning the page and getting an idea of its content and structure from just looking at the headings.)

Comment: RobinZigmond, would you mind changing your second example with `<h2>` to **not** have `aria-level="2"` since it's already implied given the h2? It's probably just a copy/paste error from your first example.

Comment: I have seen valid reasons why a "higher" heading (eg, h2) is a smaller font than a "lower" heading (eg h3). It's just a styling preference and the size of the font doesn't matter. What's important, as you said, is the structuring and if a heading needs a sub-heading, the level **number** needs to be appropriate, regardless of the font size.

Comment: @slugolicious thanks for catching that - as you guessed, it was failure to cleanup after copy-paste, it's fixed now. (I'd have been happy if you'd done the edit yourself but no worries.)

Comment: I actually didn’t think of doing it myself. I agree that would’ve been easier.